# How to consilidate/merge Podcasts in MediaMonkey

Tags: podcasts, mediamonkey, podcatcher

I recently moved from iTunes to MediaMonkey as my media manager and podcatcher.

Now I have the problem that MediaMonkey shows me a lot of dublicted podcast subscriptions as you can see in the screenshot

[image: MediaMonkey Podcasts]

How can I merge these Podcasts together?